# point of Byte and Short in Java (I've read the other questions)

Tags: java, byte, short

My question is:
If I got it right from the Java disassembly, when I use

```
byte a=3,b=5;
System.out.println(a+b);
```

would actually use int instead of byte. Also all local memory slots are 4B just as stack slots. I realize that allocating a byte array would probably act more efficiently, but is it true that using a single byte value is ultimately inefficient? (The same point for short)

Comment: My advice: use byte when you need to deal with *bytes*. Use int when you need to deal with *numbers*. They're not quite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule of performance tuning should be to write simple, clear code.

In this example, there is no performance difference and even if there were the println() takes 10,000x times longer making any difference notional.

---

How a program appears in byte-code and how it appears in native code is different.

Not all slots are 4-bytes in the JVM. e.g. a reference on a 64-bit machine can be 8-bytes but it still uses one "slot"

Your machine doesn't have slots. It does have registers which are typically 32-bit or 64-bit.

In your example, byte operations are used, which are just as efficient as int operations, and can produce a different result so they are still required.

Note: an object with `byte` or `short` fields can be smaller than one with a `int` fields.

In this example, the JVM can calculate `c` once so it doesn't need `a` or `b`

Comment: So basically despite the fact that on 64-bit machine int (as a Java variable) will be 4B and a pointer/reference will be 8B, the VM will treat them both as atomic local variables. Is this correct?

Comment: @George Penn, Correct. However if you use `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` on a 64-bit JVM, references will be 4-bytes instead of 8-bytes. ;)

Answer (score 2):

**`+`** is integer operation. that is why

```
byte c = a+b; // compile error
```

you should use

```
int c = a + b
```

or

```
byte c = (byte)(a+b);
```

My advice is use `int` in order not to cast every time. If you always deal with `byte` use byte otherwise use `int`

Comment: Point taken, what I meant was System.out.println(a+b);

Answer (score 2):

It's important to realize that in Java the existence of `byte` and `short` are not primarily to have an integer data type with a smaller range. In almost all cases where (sufficiently small) numeric values are stored an `int` will be used, even if the valid range is just 0-100.

`byte` and `short` are used when *some external factor* restricts the data to be handled to those ranges. They simply exist to simplify interaction with such systems.

For example, file systems these days store byte streams. You *could* use `int` for all those reading/writing operations, but having a `byte` data type simplifies the operation and makes that distinction explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `byte a=3,b=5;` as `final byte a=3,b=5;` so that when this statement `byte c = a+b;` will get executed it will take `byte` not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Define inefficient.

Yes, the memory footprint might seem inefficient, but keep in mind most processors today are 32bit (or even 64bit). Storing a byte in only 8 bits would require the processor to get the 32 bits of address space and shift and clean it so the necessary 8 bits are in the right spot.

Comment: Inefficient in the sense that an int would be:
a) faster
b) of greater use
c) of the same memory footprint
Thanks