# No sense in using byte, short and char

Tags: java, binary, operators, short, type-promotion

I'm studying the book for the JAVA OCA certification. I'm in the chapter of binary operator. The book mentions the following rule.

`byte`, `short` and `char` will be promoted to int when they use binary operators.

So, at the moment, if I define and initialize a variable of type short or byte it will be automatically converted to int.
In the book, it says `=` assignment is a binary operator.

Is there any point of using these kind of variables?

How can I print this type of variable in java?

Comment: Probably be the duplicate question [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582233/why-byte-and-short-values-are-promoted-to-int-when-an-expression-is-evaluated)

Comment: `byte a = -1` is not converted to an `int`. It's promoted to an `int` if you use a *binary operator* (or arithmetic operator); `byte b = a + (byte)1; // < --int`

Comment: Assignment is not really a binary operator.  Either the book is confusing, or you read it wrong.

Comment: @Vin Please be careful about editing when there's a quote involved.  If the OP says that a book says "assignment is a binary operator", then you really should not make a major change, such as changing to "operation", unless you know what book he's talking about and know what it says.

Comment: @ajb I have just edited the post to remove 'Thanks. The said edit has been done by another user. You may rollback if you think it conflicts with OP's intent.

Comment: @Vin I'm really sorry.  I got careless.

Comment: @ajb no need to be sorry. For a community edited site, you have all the rights to question anything you think is out of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such variables would not be converted to `int` whenever you define them. They will be promoted to `int` when using them together with a binary operator like the `&` operator. Get class name of an object by using:

> variablename.getClass().getName()

Answer (score -1):

Given an instance of any object, you can call its `getClass()` method to get an instance of the `Class` object that describe the type of the object.

Using the `Class` object, you can easily print its type name:

```
Integer number=Integer.valueOf(15);
System.out.println(number.getClass().getName());
```