# Why do arithmetic operations on bytes return an int in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, integer-arithmetic

Consider this code:

```
val x1: Byte = 0x00
val x2: Byte = 0x01
val x3: Byte = x1 + x2;
```

This gives a compile error, because the result of adding 2 `Byte`s is an `Int`.

To work around this, I need to manually cast the result back into a byte:

```
val x3: Byte = (x1 + x2).toByte()
```

This is very counter-intuative. Why do the arithmetic operators work like this?

Comment: `Why do the arithmetic operators work like this?` is very hard to answer without asking the developers of Kotlin. It's just the way it's defined: `public operator fun plus(other: Byte): Int`

Comment: because Java (as well as other C-like languages) promotes types narrower than int to int [Why byte and short values are promoted to int when an expression is evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27582233/995714), [Why byte and short division results in int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41034555/995714), [Why are integer types promoted during addition in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29817927/995714), [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/995714)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This is very counter-intuative. Why do the arithmetic operators work like this?

It is also an exact copy of the Java semantics. Java has no bytecode for the addition of two `byte`s, `char`s or `short`s. While Kotlin could have decided to change the semantics and emit more complex bytecode, the choice to stay aligned with Java has its merits.

A similar question would be "why is `Byte` a signed type?" and the answer would be along similar lines. Kotlin is intended to feel familiar to experienced Java developers.